What is count param in spring boot actuator healthcheck?
I've setup my app with actuator, and I see that it's running the following:
select count(?) from systables
What is the ? in this? I would assume it's not *.
Is there a way I can customize this query or param?
I see the following in the code:
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.ConnectionPool;


dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");


I would say it's parameter. It's not matter what you bind. select count(1) from ... is the same as select count(*) from ... But select (distinct 1) from ... is always 1 (or 0 if empty)

The question mark is there likely because of a binded parameter to the validation query. And probably being called here Though I don't think this (the query) is coming from the actuator, it is probably configured in the Pool library you are using. And yes you can customize it but it depends on the pool you are using. Let me know and I can add an answer with the correct one.

updated the post with more details;
